# create an oracle sequence mechanism with starting as AAA001 once AAA999 it should increment by AAB001 and so

Tags: oracle, plsql, sequence

We are new to PLSQL technology . we need the below function or logic for create an oracle sequence mechanism with starting as AAA001 once AAA999 it should increment by AAB001 and so on .

Ex:

AAA001
AAA002
..
AAA999
AAB001
AAB002
..
AAB999
AAC001
AAC002
..

etc

Could somebody help me on this.

We tried different logic but nothing works out. could someone help on this

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40008704/266304) do what you want? If you adjust the divisor from 10000 to 1000, as you want three digits in stead of 4?